# passing mutable MTLBuffer between two Metal compute encoders swift

Tags: metal

In some objective c classes I have a buffer that is used by two sequential metal pipelines. One kernel processes values based on the rgb luminance of the picture and writes to the mutable buffer and the next draws out a waveform graph based on the data in the first. It's based on the osx shader described here [USING METAL PERFORMANCE SHADERS WITH CORE IMAGE](https://martinhering.me/post/using-metal-performance-shaders-with-core-image).

I managed to convert this from osx to IOS which is working great but I am now  trying to convert it to swift to make it more flexible for me in the future. I have other filters I'd like to write and the translating process is also teaching me a lot about how metal pipelines work.

This is where it's breaking down. The graph it draws has one horizontal coloured line fluttering up and down. Close but no cigar. I wondered if it had something to do with how the buffers were created in swift vs objective c. Here's an example of the original:

```
size_t columnBufSize = sizeof(UInt64)*inputTexture.width*inputTexture.height;
id<MTLBuffer> columnDataRed = [kDevice newBufferWithLength:columnBufSize options:0];
```

but when I translate this in swift It's not behaving as expected.

```
 let columnBufSize: size_t = MemoryLayout<UInt64>.size * inputTexture!.width  * inputTexture!.height
 let columnDataRed: MTLBuffer  = kDevice.makeBuffer( length: columnBufSize, options: .storageModeShared)!
```

It looks like only the last value is passed into the second computeEncoder.

What am I missing?

for completion, here is the full code in objective c

```
+ (BOOL)processWithInputs:(NSArray<id<CIImageProcessorInput>> *)inputs arguments:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)arguments output:(id<CIImageProcessorOutput>)output error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error
{
    id<MTLComputePipelineState> renderComputerState = kParadeComputePipelineState;



    id<CIImageProcessorInput> input = inputs.firstObject;

    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = output.metalCommandBuffer;
    commandBuffer.label = @"com.martinhering.WaveformKernel";
    id<MTLTexture> inputTexture = input.metalTexture;
    id<MTLTexture> outputTexture = output.metalTexture;

    MTLSize threadgroupCount = MTLSizeMake(inputTexture.width, inputTexture.height, 1);
    MTLSize _threadgroupSize = MTLSizeMake(16, 16, 1);

    threadgroupCount.width  = (inputTexture.width  + _threadgroupSize.width -  1) / _threadgroupSize.width;
    threadgroupCount.height = (inputTexture.height + _threadgroupSize.height - 1) / _threadgroupSize.height;


    size_t columnBufSize = sizeof(UInt64)*inputTexture.width*inputTexture.height;
    id<MTLBuffer> columnDataRed = [kDevice newBufferWithLength:columnBufSize options:0];
    id<MTLBuffer> columnDataGreen = [kDevice newBufferWithLength:columnBufSize options:0];
    id<MTLBuffer> columnDataBlue = [kDevice newBufferWithLength:columnBufSize options:0];

    id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> computeEncoder;

    computeEncoder = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
    [computeEncoder setComputePipelineState:kWaveformComputePipelineState];
    [computeEncoder setTexture:inputTexture atIndex:0];
    [computeEncoder setBuffer:columnDataRed offset:0 atIndex:0];
    [computeEncoder setBuffer:columnDataGreen offset:0 atIndex:1];
    [computeEncoder setBuffer:columnDataBlue offset:0 atIndex:2];
    [computeEncoder setSamplerState:kSamplerState atIndex:0];
    [computeEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:threadgroupCount
                   threadsPerThreadgroup:_threadgroupSize];

    [computeEncoder endEncoding];


    computeEncoder = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
    [computeEncoder setComputePipelineState:renderComputerState];
    [computeEncoder setTexture:inputTexture atIndex:0];
    [computeEncoder setTexture:outputTexture atIndex:1];
    [computeEncoder setBuffer:columnDataRed offset:0 atIndex:0];
    [computeEncoder setBuffer:columnDataGreen offset:0 atIndex:1];
    [computeEncoder setBuffer:columnDataBlue offset:0 atIndex:2];
    [computeEncoder setSamplerState:kSamplerState atIndex:0];
    [computeEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:threadgroupCount
                   threadsPerThreadgroup:_threadgroupSize];

    [computeEncoder endEncoding];
    return YES;
}
```

Here is my translation

```
override class func process(with inputs: [CIImageProcessorInput]?, arguments: [String : Any]?, output: CIImageProcessorOutput) throws {

    guard
        let kDevice = device,
        let commandBuffer = output.metalCommandBuffer,
        let input = inputs?.first,
        let defaultLibrary: MTLLibrary = kDevice.makeDefaultLibrary()
    else  {
        return
    }

     let samplerDescriptor = MTLSamplerDescriptor()
    let  kSamplerState = kDevice.makeSamplerState(descriptor: samplerDescriptor)

    samplerDescriptor.sAddressMode = .clampToEdge
    samplerDescriptor.tAddressMode = .clampToEdge
    samplerDescriptor.minFilter = .nearest
    samplerDescriptor.magFilter = .nearest
    samplerDescriptor.normalizedCoordinates = false


      var kWaveformComputePipelineState: MTLComputePipelineState?         
      var kParadeComputePipelineState: MTLComputePipelineState?


    if let aFunction = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "scope_waveform_compute") {
        kWaveformComputePipelineState = try? kDevice.makeComputePipelineState(function: aFunction)
    }

    if let aFunction = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "scope_waveform_parade") {
        kParadeComputePipelineState = try? kDevice.makeComputePipelineState(function: aFunction)
    }






    commandBuffer.label = "com.martinhering.WaveformKernel"

    weak var inputTexture: MTLTexture? = input.metalTexture
    weak var outputTexture: MTLTexture? = output.metalTexture

    var threadgroupCount: MTLSize = MTLSizeMake(inputTexture!.width, inputTexture!.height, 1)
    let threadgroupSize: MTLSize = MTLSizeMake(16, 16, 1)
    threadgroupCount.width = (inputTexture!.width  + threadgroupSize.width - 1) / threadgroupSize.width
    threadgroupCount.height = (inputTexture!.height + threadgroupSize.height - 1) / threadgroupSize.height


    let columnBufSize: size_t = MemoryLayout<UInt64>.size * inputTexture!.width  * inputTexture!.height

    let columnDataRed: MTLBuffer  = kDevice.makeBuffer( length: columnBufSize, options: .storageModeShared)!
    let columnDataGreen: MTLBuffer  = kDevice.makeBuffer( length: columnBufSize, options: .storageModeShared)!
    let columnDataBlue: MTLBuffer  = kDevice.makeBuffer( length: columnBufSize, options: .storageModeShared)!


    weak var computeEncoder: MTLComputeCommandEncoder?

    computeEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()
    computeEncoder?.setComputePipelineState(kWaveformComputePipelineState!)
    computeEncoder?.setTexture(inputTexture, index: 0)
    computeEncoder?.setBuffer(columnDataRed, offset: 0, index: 0)
    computeEncoder?.setBuffer(columnDataGreen, offset: 0, index: 1)
    computeEncoder?.setBuffer(columnDataBlue, offset: 0, index: 2)
    computeEncoder?.setSamplerState(kSamplerState, index: 0)
    computeEncoder?.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupCount, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadgroupSize)
    computeEncoder?.endEncoding()


    computeEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()
    computeEncoder?.setComputePipelineState(kParadeComputePipelineState!)
    computeEncoder?.setTexture(inputTexture, index: 0)
    computeEncoder?.setTexture(outputTexture, index: 1)
    computeEncoder?.setBuffer(columnDataRed, offset: 0, index: 0)
    computeEncoder?.setBuffer(columnDataGreen, offset: 0, index: 1)
    computeEncoder?.setBuffer(columnDataBlue, offset: 0, index: 2)
    computeEncoder?.setSamplerState(kSamplerState, index: 0)
    computeEncoder?.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupCount, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadgroupSize)
    computeEncoder?.endEncoding()
```

//        return true

```
}
```

Comment: Two concurrent pipelines? Did you mean sequential? Also, what exactly do you mean by "only the last value is passed into the second computeEncoder"? What last value? Last of what? You're using two compute encoders and the second one draws? What leads you to conclude that only the last value is passed?

Comment: Forgive me yes. Not very clear. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: The first issue that jumps out at me is that you're setting properties on the sampler descriptor after using it to create the sampler state object. That doesn't affect the sampler state object. The properties of the descriptor at the time of the state object creation are what's used. After that, the state object has no further relationship with the descriptor. Changing the descriptor could be useful if you were to create another state object from it but has no effect on the existing state object. The only property you're setting that differs from the defaults is `normalizedCoordinates`.

Comment: Spot on. Thank you so so much. Makes perfect sense now. It jumped into life immediately as soon as I switched the creation of the sampler state to the end.

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to Ken Thomases for this; it was simple in the end.

You have to set the properties of the sampler Descriptor before you create the samplerState.

```
let samplerDescriptor = MTLSamplerDescriptor()
  samplerDescriptor.normalizedCoordinates = false
  let  kSamplerState = kDevice.makeSamplerState(descriptor: samplerDescriptor)
```